# Installing Broadcom driver failed to install Acer AspireOne

Tags: wireless, drivers, broadcom

I'm sure there is an answer to my problem somewhere, but I'm not able to find it.

I'm a complete newbie, just downloaded Ubuntu 12.04 LTS a few days ago. It's on double boot at the moment as I wanted to make sure it's gonna work for me.

As my wi-fi didn't work, I've followed the steps mentioned here: [Installing Broadcom Wireless Drivers](https://askubuntu.com/questions/55868/how-to-install-broadcom-wireless-drivers-bcm43xx), number 51. All went ok, but when I tried to install it (after reboot) I got an error message:

su@ubuntu:~$ sudo apt-get install 
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `newline'

I imagine it's a simple error, but I have no idea what. Sorry to bother you, but I don't want to make too much of a mess and create more problems.

Oh, I did try to install the driver through "Addistional Driver", but got an error message there, too.

Please keep in mind that I have no idea what I'm doing and am just trying to follow directions :-).

Thank you.

Suzana

Comment: Please edit your question to tell us what you found about your wireless card and what you tried from #51.

Answer (score 0):

I also had the same issue with ubuntu 11.10, 12.10.Problem was that Wifi was not working on bcm43142 sony-vaio-fit-15e. BUT when I tried to install ubuntu 13.10 , I checked the option of " Install this third party software " and it worked for me !!

See step 2 in this link: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/install-desktop-latest